# Getting jQuery auto complete to work IntelliJ 10.0.3

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, intellij-idea

Greetings!
I set up jQuery as a global library in IntelliJ 10.0.3 but I can't get it to auto-complete jQuery methods :-(

I followed this guide to [JavaScript Libraries in Intellij IDEA 10](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/11/javascript-libraries-in-intellij-idea-10/), but with no luck.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After specifying the global jQuery library you need to make sure that it is defined in your file completion scope:
1. Open Settings|JavaScript Libraries|Usage Scope.
2. Find the file you want to set the completion for at the right pane.
3. Select jQuery library from drop-down list (it must be checked).
That should be it. This is not needed if your jQuery library is either under the project root or have been downloaded using "Download library" intention. In the latter case the library is "attached" to your project file automatically but for other files you have to set it manually. Note that you can specify the jQuery library for the entire project or any of its subdirectories using the same "Usage Scope" tree.

Comment: .... that's the thing, I have the library defined globally but it does not show up under scope. In fact, when I go to Setting|JavaScript Libraries | Usage Scope, all I have in the right pane is '- Project' with a little file icon and that's all.

Comment: There is the second "Library" column. If you click in it, you should get the drop-down list with your library. Can you see it?

Comment: when I go to 'Project Structure' I have '-Project Setting-' -> Libraries and '-Platform Settings-' -> Global Settings, is that what you're asking about?

Comment: ... fixed it, I got a check mark on the library I created and now it seems to be showing up ok, thanks! That's now on the 10.5 version, upgraded to it last night.